# Create CSV File with PHP

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv

I want to create a **new .csv file** (without opening the raw file first via [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)).
So far I have tried this:

```
$list[] = array
(
    "Name" => "John",
    "Gender" => "M",
    "Age" => "21"
);
$timestamp0 = date("Y-m-d H:i:sa", time());
$datetime = new DateTime($timestamp0);
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));
$timestamp = $datetime->format("Y-m-d_H-i");

$filename = __DIR__ . "/file/" . $timestamp . ".csv";

$header = array("name", "gender", "age");
file_put_contents($filename, implode("\n", $list)); // error here bcs array given :')
```

My questions are:

> 1. How can I change array 2d to csv?

Very need your help :( Thank you so much :")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) with `w` will create the file if does not exist:

```
$list = [
    ["Name" => "John", "Gender" => "M"],
    ["Name" => "Doe", "Gender" => "M"],
    ["Name" => "Sara", "Gender" => "F"]
];

$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
//Write the header
fputcsv($fp, array_keys($list[0]));
//Write fields
foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

If you don't like [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) you can use this alternative:

```
$list = [
    ["Name" => "John", "Gender" => "M"],
    ["Name" => "Doe", "Gender" => "M"],
    ["Name" => "Sara", "Gender" => "F"]
];

$csvArray = ["header" => implode (",", array_keys($list[0]))] + array_map(function($item) {
    return implode (",", $item);
}, $list);

file_put_contents($filename, implode ("\n", $csvArray));
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Im sorry forget to change, Im using array multidimensional, what should I do? :')

Comment: Just update the question with your array and I will assist you in a better alternative ;)

Comment: @ismail RBOUH, -1because it not a perfect way to create CSV file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: @HareshVidja I'm still waiting for you to remove the downvote ! Because it was the OP request to not use `open` and `fputcsv`. However, I've updated the answer for future users ;)  Thank you ;)

Comment: You have not given perfect solution first time so I have given down vote... You have to think first for give perfect solution...  thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
$list[]=array ("name","gender","age"); // push header here
$list[] = array("John","M","21"); // push record here

$timestamp0     = date("Y-m-d H:i:sa",time());
$datetime       = new DateTime($timestamp0);
$datetime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Jakarta'));
$timestamp      = $datetime->format("Y-m-d_H-i");

$filename = __DIR__ . "/file/" . $timestamp . ".csv";

$fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

For more detail read php manual about CSV file. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php